# Add Aggregate Column to Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame that looks like:

```
| id | value | bin |
|----+-------+-----|
|  1 |   3.4 |   2 |
|  2 |   2.6 |   1 |
|  3 |   1.8 |   1 |
|  4 |   9.6 |   2 |
```

I have a function `f` that takes an array of values and returns a number.  I want to add a column to the above data frame where the value for the new column in each row is the value of `f` for all the `value` entries that have the same `bin` entry, i.e:

```
| id | value | bin | f_value       |
|----+-------+-----+---------------|
|  1 |   3.4 |   2 | f([3.4, 9.6]) |
|  2 |   2.6 |   1 | f([2.6, 1.8]) |
|  3 |   1.8 |   1 | f([2.6, 1.8]) |
|  4 |   9.6 |   2 | f([3.4, 9.6]) |
```

Since I need to aggregate all `value`s per `bin`, I cannot use the `withColumn` function to add this new column.  What is the best way to do this until user defined aggregation functions make there way into Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code is not tested, but just an idea.

In Hive, it can be done like this using [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features) function.

```scala
val newDF = sqlContext.sql(
    "select bin, collect_list() from aboveDF group by bin")
```

Next `join` `aboveDF` and `newDF` on bin.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I was hoping to not have to invoke a join.  Thanks!